Verify that Bicep can return values from Azure Key vault
if i'm using e.g following lines in my .bicepparam file to get secret frp, Key Vault, is there way to verify that bicep is really able to read the values correctly?
using './main.bicep'

param secureUserName = getSecret('exampleSubscription', 'exampleResourceGroup', 'exampleKeyVault', 'exampleSecretUserName')
param securePassword = getSecret('exampleSubscription', 'exampleResourceGroup', 'exampleKeyVault', 'exampleSecretPassword')

If I read documentation right you can't just output the secureUserName because doesn’t allow to retrieve the actual value(by design).

As mentioned in the document, it is not possible to return values of a key vault secret and keys by design as they are meant to be confidential. Try below approach to verify that the key vault values can return with bicep.
Create a sample resource (eg: storage account), pass the secret values and try referring it in the bicep code as I have given below.
param secretusername string = 'myvaultjah'
param password string = 'newsec'
param location string = resourceGroup().location
resource sample 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts@2023-01-01' = {
  name: '${secretusername}2n'
  location: location
  sku: {
    name: 'Standard_LRS'
  }
}
output sampleoutput string = secretusername
output pwd string = password

Output:
In this way, you can check from the output block whether the values are correctly taken by the bicep code.

